# How to get total size of multiple files php

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I am trying to upload multiple files with single input and i wanted to limit the total size of all files to be less than 100 MB. How can i do it?
This is my code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
           $fileName = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
           $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
           $maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024 /* 100MB */;
           if(empty($fileName)) {
             echo 'Please select photos to upload!';
           } else if(!in_array( $fileExt, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'))) {
             echo 'Only photos, videos and audios allowed. If you have one or more files that is not in our <a href="#">supported extensions</a> directory, please remove it!';
           } else if($_FILES['upload']['size'][$i]>$maxFileSize) {
             echo 'Your file\s exceed the limit of 100MB capacity';
           } else {
             echo "Uploaded";
           }
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div>
       <label for='upload'>Add Attachments:</label>
       <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
   </div>

   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
 </form>
```

It seems that i can't get the sum of the size all files. How can i do this?
And thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use the configuration to set a max post size of 100Mb. http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: no... i want the sum of the size of all these size. as it is an array it is returning the size of different files.

Comment: Also be aware that it is not safe to check a file type based on the file extension. it is better to use fileinfo : http://php.net/manual/book.fileinfo.php

Comment: that is what `post_max_size does` : it limits the size of the whole post request so if you set the limit to `100M`, you will be able to upload one `100Mb` file or 2 `50Mb` files but uploading 2 `60Mb` files will fail because the sum of the two sizes is greater than the `post_max_size`

Comment: I tried every answer but none is working.. can you tell me any other way to upload multiple files

Comment: what do you mean by *it does not work* ? do you get an error ? no result ? does your php config allows file uploads and multiple file uploads ? did you check for [upload errors](http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php) ?

Comment: No everything is correct. but its not working as i expected it to be...

Comment: then, you have to be more precise on what you get and what you expect to get a more appropriate answer

Comment: The below answers are not summing up the file's sizes. As it is an array.. it is seperating the files sizes and its displaying as => '025644'. 0 is the size of one file('How can it be?') and 25644 is the size of another

Comment: Anyway, do you know any other way to do this? do you have your own code?

Comment: I just tried the solution I proposed (using array_sum) with two files (22Kb and 29 Kb) and `$totalFileSize` contains `int(51177)` which is the sum of the size of the two files

Comment: try to echo $totalFileSize. And add a '<br>' tag to it at the end. See if it splits or not.

Comment: just like I said in my previous comment, `$totalFileSize` contains 51177 which is the sum of the size of the two files. see the edit in my answer to get the full code I used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get the size of all uploaded files into your code, you can use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-sum.php), there is no need to use a loop.

```
$totalFileSize = array_sum($_FILES['upload']['size']);
```

this will give you the size in bytes of all files. then you can compare it to your max size :

```
$maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024 /* 100MB */;
if ($totalFileSize > $maxFileSize) {
    echo 'Your files exceed the limit of 100MB capacity';
}
```

---

based on your code, here is the full code with `array_sum` to get the total file size

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0) {
        // compute the total size of the uploaded files
        $totalFileSize = array_sum($_FILES['upload']['size']);
        echo 'upload size : ' . $totalFileSize . ' bytes';
        $maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
        // check if the upload size is less than the max allowed
        if ($totalFileSize > $maxFileSize) {
            echo 'Your files exceed the limit of 100MB capacity';
        } else {
            // upload size is OK, process files
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
                $fileName = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                if (empty($fileName)) {
                    echo 'Please select photos to upload!';
                } else {
                    if (!in_array($fileExt, ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'])) {
                        echo 'Only photos, videos and audios allowed. If you have one or more files that is not in our <a href="#">supported extensions</a> directory, please remove it!';
                    } else {
                        echo "Uploaded";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for='upload'>Add Attachments:</label>
        <input id='upload' name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
    </div>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to calculate it inside the loop. I have put **$total_file_size** variable to do that below.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){

    $total_file_size = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {

       $total_file_size += $_FILES['upload']['size'][$i];

       $fileName = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
       $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
       $maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024 /* 100MB */;
       if(empty($fileName)) {
         echo 'Please select photos to upload!';
       } else if(!in_array( $fileExt, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'))) {
         echo 'Only photos, videos and audios allowed. If you have one or more files that is not in our <a href="#">supported extensions</a> directory, please remove it!';
       } else if($_FILES['upload']['size'][$i]>$maxFileSize) {
         echo 'Your file\s exceed the limit of 100MB capacity';
       } else {
         echo "Uploaded";
       }
    }
    }
}
?>
```